# How do I run multiple events in a specific order?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to c# and has a question about events on a WPF application. I have two events (Button_Click and myslider_ValueChanged) and would like the myslider_ValueChanged to run after Button_Click. I have tried using EventHandler but it both events still run at the same time. Is there an easier way to do this such as a nested event? Any help is appreciated, thanks. I have attached my EventHandler attempt below.

```
    namespace program
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {

            public event EventHandler _Click;
            public event EventHandler _ValueChanged;

            protected void On_Click(EventArgs e)
            {
                if (_Click != null)
                {
                    _Click(this, e);
                }
            }

            protected void On_ValueChanged(EventArgs e)
            {
                On_Click(EventArgs.Empty);

            }

            private void Initialize()
            {
                _Click += new EventHandler(_Click);
                _ValueChanged += new EventHandler(_ValueChanged);
                _Click += _ValueChanged;
            }


            private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
              //Code here
            }

            private void myslider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
            {
            //Code here
            }
```

Comment: This is exactly like it should. What do you want to do? If a user clicks on a button the button handler should be executed. The same with the slider.

Comment: When you run the program both the myslider and button activate. I only want the slider to be active after the button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have myslider_ValueChanged call a different method to perform the work, then call that new method from button_click.

For example:

```
       private void myslider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
           HandleValueSliderChanged();
        }
        private void HandleValueSliderChanged() {
          //Code here
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //Code here
           HandleValueSliderChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this still seems to run at the same time as the button though, not after it. The main problem is I have a Convert.ToDouble(s); that checks if the input is a valid number, and if not it enters an error. when the program starts the slider = 3 and all the user input is 0 which in my case is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear in your original question (by running, you mean enabled). In this case, you can remove the slider event handler (unless you need it for something else), set the slider Enabled property to false in the designer, and set the slider Enabled property to true in the Button event handler.

Answer (score 0):

So just set myslider.IsEnabled=true within the Button click event. And Set it to false in in the Initialize method before.